# Sending mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Im trying to send bulk of emails containing passwords to the students taking an exam in a particular subject.Now, Im having an error "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error () SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host." What could possibly be the problem?

my code as follows:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

//date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('PHPMailer-phpmailer-5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php');
include("PHPMailer-phpmailer-5.2.0/class.smtp.php");  //optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail                = new PHPMailer();


$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host          = "localhost";
$mail->SMTPAuth      = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;                  // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent
$mail->Host          = "mail.yahoo.com"; // sets the SMTP server*/
$mail->Port          = 26;                 
$mail->Username      = "***********@yahoo.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password      = "****************";        // SMTP account password
$mail->From = "*************@yahoo.com";
$mail->FromName =  "Exam System";
//$mail->IsHTML(true);


while ($row_email = mysql_fetch_array ($email)) {

  $mail->Subject    = "Subject: ".$row_email['subject_description']."";
  $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
  $mail->Body       = "This is your password for ".$row_email['exam_title']." : ".$row_email['pass_password']."";
  $mail->AddAddress($row_email['stud_email']);

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row_email['stud_email']) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
  } else {
    echo "Message sent to :" . $row_email['stud_email'] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row_email['stud_email']) . ')<br />';
  }
  // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
  $mail->ClearAddresses();
  $mail->ClearAttachments();
}


mysql_free_result($email);
?>
```

Comment: Port 26 looks wrong. SMTP usually is sent on port 25. Try removing this line, so that the library defaults to the correct port?

Comment: Set secutiry (TLS/SSL) and try to change port to 465.

Comment: Still Im having the same error. Ive changed my port to 465 and added the line:$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; Can I use gmail even if my email account is on yahoo?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...

add this code for Set secutiry

// if you're using SSL
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// OR use TLS
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **gmail**, as i am not aware of Yahoo's SMTP server. [Also, use the gmail credentials (username, password)]

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SendMailWithGmailSMTP($author, $email, $text)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host     = "localhost"; // Sets the SMTP hosts
    $mail->Port     = 587; // Sets the default SMTP server port.
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false; // Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables.
    $mail->Username = "...@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "...";
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $author;
    $mail->CharSet  = "ISO-8859-9";
    $mail->AddAddress("...@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject  = "Hi. This is a Subject!";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $text;
    if($mail->Send()) return true;  else echo '<script language="javascript">alert("'.$mail->ErrorInfo.'");</script>'; 
}
```

Write this function for send mail and call this function like this:

```
SendMailWithGmailSMTP("Aziz Yılmaz", "...@gmail.com", "Bla bla bla")
```

Comment: Is your codes safe? what if i get banned? is it safe without using smtpauth?